# Which method to call in order to convert given string to UpperCase in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, deprecated

Given a String:

```
val myString: Any = "baa baa bLack shEEp"
```

I would like to have a new string (as myString is immutable of course) containing:

```
BAA BAA BLACK SHEEP
```

Checked in https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-upper-case.html
But it says it is deprecated. I must say - it works, but probably there's a reason for that.
Any idea?

Comment: Why `Any`? Cant you use `String` as type, or not declate type so its inferred from the value?

Comment: It's deprecated because the locale used is ambiguous.

Comment: The docs literally tell you to use ``uppercase()`` instead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple you just need to do this:

```kotlin
val myString = "baa baa bLack shEEp" 
println(myString.uppercase())
```

Answer (score 0):

the method `toUpperCase()` is indeed deprecated. here's an example how to achieve upper case:

```
val myString: Any = "baa baa bLack shEEp"
if (myString is String){
    println(myString.uppercase())
}
```

Comment: You really don't need the `Any` type, and thus the type check. Just use `val myString = "your literal"` and it will already be of the correct type